# What is better, do a union and then a join o do a join in all the tables of the union?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, union

I have to do a union of 5 tables and then do a join with other table. Which way have more efficiency do the union of the 5 tables and then the join o do the join on each tables and then de union?.

Comment: Write down all the potential queries and compare their execution plans.

Comment: After UNION the server cannot use any index in separate tables which were UNIONed - the dataset have no any index. Whereas each separate subquery may be optimizes using indices. So UNION of final queries must be more effective. Or at least not less effective.

Comment: @cris; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very nice question.
I test the question on two server configuration:

For Single Thread Server :
`join` after `union` was much better than `join` 5 tables and then `union` the result because for every `join` you should do the same index scan.

For Multi Thread Server :
`join` Before `union` was much better because of the max degree of parallelism.
All joins will be processed at the same time then the union will happen.

**Join After Union**[image: Join After Union]

**Join Before Union**

[image: Join Before Union]

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to close this question as two broad.  But let me point out why you have not provided enough information.

First, you specify "union" rather than "union all", which means that your query needs to remove duplicates.  That is an expensive operation.  Do you want to do it before or after the `join`?

- If there are many matches in the other table for a given value in `union` query, then you want to remove duplicates *before* the `join`.
- If the `join` to the other table filters out many rows from the `union` query, then you want to join first and remove after.

Indexing matters as well.

- If you have only an index on the other table, then doing the `union` first might be a good idea.
- If you have only indexes on the tables in the union, then you might want to split apart the union into five separate `join` queries.

Just based on these two issues, it is not possible to provide a simple answer to your question.  And, there are many other considerations as well -- table partitioning, filtering, aggregation, `order by`, etc.